# Why does javac complain about generics unrelated to the class' type arguments?

Tags: java, generics, javac, unchecked

**Please read the comments in the code in order, the question details are there.**
Why is this difference happening?
Please quote the JLS if possible.

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Suppose I have a generic class
 * @param <T> with a type argument.
 */
class Generic<T> {
    // Apart from using T normally,
    T paramMethod() { return null; }
    // the class' interface also contains Generic Java Collections
    // which are not using T, but unrelated types.
    List<Integer> unrelatedMethod() { return null; }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Test {
    // If I use the class properly (with qualified type arguments)
    void properUsage() {
        Generic<String> g = new Generic<String>();

        // everything works fine.
        String s = g.paramMethod();
        List<Integer> pos = g.unrelatedMethod();

        // OK error: incompatible types: List<String> := List<Integer>
        List<String> thisShouldErrorCompile = g.unrelatedMethod();
    }

    // But when I use the raw type, *ALL* the generics support is gone, even the Collections'.
    void rawUsage() {
        // Using Generic<?> as the type turns fixes the warnings below.
        Generic g = new Generic();

        // OK error: incompatible types: String := Object
        String s = g.paramMethod();

        // WTF warning: unchecked conversion: List<Integer> := raw List
        List<Integer> pos = g.unrelatedMethod();

        // WTF warning: unchecked conversion: List<String> := raw List
        List<String> thisShouldErrorCompile = g.unrelatedMethod();
    }
}
```

#### Side note

I originally found this in IntelliJ IDEA, but I guess that compiler is compatible with javac because when I compiled the above code with the following it gave the same errors/warnings.

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_05
$ javac Test.java -Xlint:unchecked
...
$ javac Test.java -Xlint:unchecked -source 1.5 -target 1.5
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [JLS 4.8 Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged.

and

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

Which - if you read it carefully - implies that **all** types are *erased*, not just the type you left out.