# Java compiler bug with generics

Tags: java, generics, javac

a rather unusual behavior has occurred while I was using generics the other day. The compile could no longer determine properly the return type of a method inside a generic class that had a type argument.

I am basically having 4 classes:

```
AbstractModel, ConcreteModel, AbstractService< AbstractModel > and ConcreteService< Model >
```

In AbstractService I have a simple list of Longs and a method "getListOfLongs". Now something very very strange happens when I try to get my list of longs:

> for(Long l :  service.getListOfLongs()){
>
> }[image]

And java compiler tells me my list is of Objects instead of longs.

You can try the example on my github: https://github.com/sashokbg/java-bug/

Comment: Did you file a bug report with Oracle?

Comment: not yet, I wanted to share it with you first

Comment: Is it fixed if you declare the generic type in your method signature, e.g., `test(AbstractService<?> service) {` ? Mixing raw types and generics is always weird.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: This isn't a bug. `service` is a raw type, so it's treated as if the method returns a raw `List`, not a `List<Long>`.

Comment: Intellij, but it is not related to the IDE. I have to try if parametrizing the service fixes it.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes it is raw, but the List<Long> has nothing to do with the parametrized type. It is weird behavior for me

Comment: @sashok_bg It's VERY weird, I know. But trust me that really is how raw types work. All generic type information is simply ignored, even if it has nothing whatsoever to do with the missing parameter.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Indeed, thank for your explanation it really makes more sense now, as weird as it is !

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: [This is a more pertinent duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314649/why-does-javac-complain-about-generics-unrelated-to-the-class-type-arguments).