# Why does the Streams API need a hint for generic type in this case?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, inferred-type

The following fails to compile:

```
    @NotNull String defaultFormatter(@Nullable Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Collection) {
            return ((Collection) value).stream()
                        .map(MyClass::defaultFormatter)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(eol));
        }
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
```

In particular, when compiled with javac, the error would be:

```
Error:(809, 94) java: incompatible types: 
      java.lang.Object cannot be converted to 
      @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull java.lang.String
```

But the following compiles just fine:

```
    @NotNull String defaultFormatter(@Nullable Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Collection) {
            Stream<String> stream = ((Collection) value).stream()
                         .map(MyClass::defaultFormatter);
            return stream.collect(Collectors.joining(eol));
        }
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
```

The only difference would be that I introduced an extra variable. Note that I didn't cast, so no semantic change.

Can anybody explain why is this needed?

Comment: Are you using `javac` or an IDE's compiler?

Comment: Both IntelliJ IDEA's syntax highlighter and confirmed by compiling with javac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it. See the section under *"A raw type is the erasure of that type"*. You need to use `Collection<?>` instead of `Collection`.

Comment: Thanks @Radiodef - this explains why it failed. The next question is in that case why am I able to assign to the explicit variable without casting? I.e. if the compiler allows this coercion, why wouldn't it allow it in an expression?

Comment: The assignment works because of [unchecked conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9). Basically any assignment of the form `AnObject<T> = AnObject` or `AnObject = AnObject<T>` is valid, the reason being backwards compatibility with old libraries.

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question. Not sure what is the etiquette when there is no answer to mark as correct though - can anybody advise?

Comment: @ddimitrov encourage Radiodef to write it as an answer. And do it before some grumpy soul with the dupe hammer comes and marks this a dupe of "What is a raw type".

Comment: @Radiodef could you paste this as an answer please?

Comment: See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This top part of this answer is basically what [Radiodef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2891664/radiodef) said in comments above. I'm not wanting to steal those words, but the answer below the `---` doesn't really work without the prior explanation.*

As pointed out by Radiodef, the reason why this doesn't work in the first case is because it's using a raw type, `Collection`. Instead, use `Collection<?>`, and it will work:

```
        return ((Collection<?>) value).stream()
                    .map(MyClass::defaultFormatter)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(eol));
```

The reason why it works with the explicit variable is because of unchecked conversion. Note that the following produces an unchecked conversion warning:

```
        Stream<String> stream = ((Collection) value).stream()
                     .map(MyClass::defaultFormatter);
```

The actual type of the expression on the RHS is `Stream`; you're allowed to coerce that to a `Stream<String>`, as described in [JLS Sec 5.1.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9):

> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw class or interface type (§4.8) `G` to any parameterized type of the form `G<T1,...,Tn>`.

---

The reason why you can't do the same without the variable is a bit more subtle. [This answer addresses the issue more directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27314919/3788176): when you use a raw type, *all* generics are erased from the type, not just ones directly related to the omitted type.

So, the type of `Stream.collect` when the `Stream` is raw is the erasure of the type when it is generic:

- `Stream.collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)` returns an `R`;
- The erasure of `R` is `Object`

so the return type of the `collect` call is `Object`, as you observe here. This can't be automatically coerced to a `List<String>` via unchecked conversion because it's not `List`.