# Type of method in parametrized interface is removed while that type is not connected with the parametrized one. Why?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have and interface:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public interface SomeInterface<T> {
    Optional<Integer> someMethod();
}
```

Let us call a method of the interface instance:

```
public class CheckInterfaceInstance {
    public void check(SomeInterface<?> instance) {
        instance.someMethod().get().doubleValue();
    }
}
```

All is good, no compilation errors.

But if I declare the argument of the `check()` method without "any type" then we have a compilation error:

```
public class CheckInterfaceInstance {
    public void check(SomeInterface instance) {   //I removed <?>
        instance.someMethod().get().doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Compiler treats the type of `instance.someMethod().get()` as Object. So it complains about not existing method `.doubleValue()`.

As you can see `Optional<Integer> someMethod()` declaration is not related to the `<T>` of `SomeInterface` at all. But the compiler misses the type of `Optional`.

Why?

Comment: "As you can see Optional<Integer> someMethod() declaration is not related to the <T> of SomeInterface at all." Raw types don't work in this way. When  you use raw types you lose the generic benefits for the current class.

Comment: `instance.someMethod().get()` returns `Object` because `instance.someMethod()` returns raw `Optional`.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314649/why-does-javac-complain-about-generics-unrelated-to-the-class-type-arguments Thanks to all!

Comment: @AndyTurner my bad, removed comment